# Windows 7: uninstall japan/chinese font support

Tags: windows-7

I often see in google results such Asian characters: `リンクのないトラックバッ`.
How can I uninstall support for such Asian chars completely, so only "dummy square chars" will show up for Asian words, but not real Asian chars.

This's possible in Win XP. It has an option. I need same setting for Win7 (Basic) x64.

Comment: Odd – most people wish to do the opposite...

Comment: What real-world scenario requires this?

Comment: I don't like to look at this nonsence for me. In google pages. It's bunch of random stuff for me, so i'd like to mask this with square chars (like WinXP).

Comment: So you prefer less information to achieve the same result? How would you differentiate between another language and a font that is embedded oddly that you don't have installed?

Comment: @Athom, I don't need to diff between another language and bad font, i just want to clear google results.

Answer (score 0):

Start -> Control Panel -> Region and Language -> Keyboard and Languages tab -> Uninstall display languages -> and from there you can remove an installed MUI.

Although I think display of characters depends on whether or not the font in question has glyphs for those Unicode code points.  If it still occurs, you may try changing your browser's default font to a font that doesn't have them.

Comment: Hm. I don't see "Uninstall display languages" item. http://shot.qip.ru/00cT7J-4k9ZG4vft/ Only "Change keyboard" button.